# Symfony 3 unable to login with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, security, authentication

First, I am not using FOSUserBundle in this project. So, let's get that out of the way.

I am able to register an user, but unable to log him in.

I verified that form is posted to LoginController and that it generates the authenticationUtils object, but it stops short of generating an error, even if there is one on line below:

> $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

Otherwise it does not generate any error. It fails silently. The _wdt continues to show as anonymous even if I provide the correct credentials.

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    UsedBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: UsedBundle:User
            property: email

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: db_provider
        form_login: 
            username_parameter: _email
```

The login controller:
UsedBundle\Controller\LoginController

```
namespace UsedBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        var_dump($_POST);
        $authUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        var_dump($error);
        var_dump($authUtils);
        if(isset($error)){
            $message = $error->getMessageData();
            var_dump($message);
        }
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername= $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,)
        );          
    }else{
        return $this->render('common/login.html.twig');         
    }

}
}
```

The form template:

app\Resources\Views\Common\login.html.twig

```
{% if error is defined and error is not null %}
{{ dump(error) }}

<div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% else %}
<form action="" method="post" name="login_form" id="login_form" >
    <div class="contact" >
        <input type="email" id="email" name="_email" class="form-control" placeholder="e-mail" value=" {% if last_username is defined %}
            {{ last_username }} 
        {% endif %}
        " />
    </div>

    <div class="contact" >
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="mot de passe" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="sub_ok btn btn-sm" name="submit" >Valider</button>
    </div>
</form>  
{% endif %}
```

The User entity has the getUsername() method set up to return the email:

```
namespace UsedBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UsedBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="avatar", message="Username already taken")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, unique=true)
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *      pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9\s_\-.]{5,50}$/",
 *      message="Minimum 5 caracteres, max 50."
 *      )
 */
private $avatar;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *      pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]{5,50}$/",
 *      message="Minimum 5 lettres, max 50."
 *      )
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *      pattern="/^.{8,50}$/",
 *      message="Minimum 8 caracteres, max 50."
 *      )
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *      pattern="/^[0-9]{10,20}$/",
 *      message="Minimum 5 lettres, max 50."
 *      )
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
private $role;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;  

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $userKey;   

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
private $userKeyTime;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
private $dateReg;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
 */
private $blogSubs;

/**
 * Many users for one city
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City",inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $cityId;

/**
 * one visitor may correspond to one user
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Visitor", mappedBy="userId")
 */
private $visitor;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->isActive = false;
    $this->role = 'ROLE_USER';
    //$this->blogSubs = 0;
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    return null;
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set avatar
 *
 * @param string $avatar
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setAvatar($avatar)
{
    $this->avatar = $avatar;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get avatar
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAvatar()
{
    return $this->avatar;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}


/**
 * Set phone
 *
 * @param string $phone
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setPhone($phone)
{
    $this->phone = $phone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phone
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhone()
{
    return $this->phone;
}

/**
 * Set isActive
 *
 * @param boolean $isActive
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setIsActive($isActive)
{
    $this->isActive = $isActive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get isActive
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIsActive()
{
    return $this->isActive;
}

/**
 * Set userKey
 *
 * @param string $email
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setUserKey( $email )
{
    $cur_time = time();
    $this->userKey = password_hash($email.$cur_time, PASSWORD_BCRYPT )."\n";
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userKey
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUserKey()
{
    return $this->userKey;
}

/**
 * Set userKeyTime
 *
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setUserKeyTime( $hours_added = null )
{
    if ( $hours_added === null ){ 
        $hours_added = 20; 
        $literal_time = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+' . $hours_added . ' hours')));
    }else{
        $literal_time = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()));
    }
    $this->userKeyTime = $literal_time;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userKeyTime
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUserKeyTime()
{
    return $this->userKeyTime;
}

/**
 * Get dateReg
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateReg()
{
    return $this->dateReg;
}

 /**
 * Set dateReg
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function setDateReg()
{
    $literal_time = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $this->dateReg = $literal_time;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set role
 *
 * @param string $role
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setRole($role)
{
    $this->role = $role;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get role
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->role;
}

/**
 * Set blogSubs
 *
 * @param string $blogSubs
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setBlogSubs($blogSubs)
{
    $this->blogSubs = $blogSubs;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get blogSubs
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBlogSubs()
{
    return $this->blogSubs;
}

/**
 * Get plainPassword
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPlainPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}



/**
 * Set cityId
 *
 * @param \UsedBundle\Entity\City $cityId
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setCityId(\UsedBundle\Entity\City $cityId = null)
{
    $this->cityId = $cityId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cityId
 *
 * @return \UsedBundle\Entity\City
 */
public function getCityId()
{
    return $this->cityId;
}

/**
 * Set models
 *
 * @param \UsedBundle\Entity\Visitor $models
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setModels(\UsedBundle\Entity\Visitor $models = null)
{
    $this->models = $models;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get models
 *
 * @return \UsedBundle\Entity\Visitor
 */
public function getModels()
{
    return $this->models;
}

/**
 * Set visitor
 *
 * @param \UsedBundle\Entity\Visitor $visitor
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setVisitor(\UsedBundle\Entity\Visitor $visitor = null)
{
    $this->visitor = $visitor;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get visitor
 *
 * @return \UsedBundle\Entity\Visitor
 */
public function getVisitor()
{
    return $this->visitor;
}
}
```

The form is submitted via Ajax, as follows:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login_form').submit(function(e) {
            var str = $("#login_form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/login",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: str,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        });
    });
});
```

I am adding the output below from Firebug. I am not exactly sure how it came about, but it shows the role property empty. Still not sure why. All users have ROLE_USER on the db

```
  object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken)#2384 (6) {
["credentials":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":private]=>
string(8) "senha444"
["providerKey":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":private]=>
string(4) "main"
["user":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
string(22) "myemail@gmail.com"
["roles":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
array(0) {
}
["authenticated":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
bool(false)
["attributes":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
array(0) {
}
```

Comment: I've add a similar issue lately and the problem was that i was trying to log in not using HTTPS whereas in the config.yml framework.session.cookie_secure was true. So the app was not able to create the cookie. Don't know if this is the same issue, but i could not log in and i had no error.

Comment: Thanks @Picoss, I do not have that parameter set at all on config.yml. I did check php.ini on the /web directory and it has no directive on that and MAMP's php info  session.cookie_secure and session.cookie_httponly are off.

Comment: Hum I think it's the url you send the POST that is not correct. You should not submit your form on /login but on /login_check instead. Or add the your firewall config login_path and check_path if you want to POST the login form on /login.

Take a look at the Symfony2 documentation on "How to build a triditional login form" : http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: @Picoss, I do not think that's necessary in this instance. Ajax does the routing to the correct controller. The set up is such that there's a login form in every page. If I put that on it will just start redirecting for no good reason.

Comment: @BernardA When you check the profiler, can you inspect the request to the `/login_check` URL ? You can inspect the previous request using the "last 10" button in the profiler. May I also suggest you to use the [debug component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/debug.html), which provides you a `dump` function, instead of `var_dump` ?

Comment: @JulienFastré, there is no request to /login_check. Form is posted by Ajax directly to /login path. Concerning the debug component, I will need some time to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Should you not configure the `login_path` in `security.yml` ? This is explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#check-path). But I do not remember if the authentification is done when the call to the route is detected, or if it is when the `username_parameter` is sent. (**EDIT** : I mean `check_path`, not `login_path`)

Comment: @JulienFastré, I am just a beginner when it comes to Symfony, but it would seem that if I post the form with Ajax, it sends it to the correct controller. And it does. If I put check_path: /login on security.yml it will generate another GET and spit out the form as such, as verified with Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

This would not work as set up above. Symfony does not play well with Ajax, so one needs to customize the login.

I have added an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921412/symfony-3-bcrypt-password-does-not-verify) with the whole setup.